# defaultProps overrides delevert props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2016

I have an simple react component that i send a bool prop to like `<MenuItem active={notificationMenu.shown} />`
but the prop don't get changed inside the component and is always true even if i pass it in on the element

```
@Radium
export class MenuItem extends Component {
  styles = {
    hidden: {
      listStyleType: "none"
    }
  }
  static propTypes = {
    active: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  }
  static defaultProps = {
    active: true
  }
  render() {
    if(this.props.active) {
      return (
        <li style={this.props.style}>
          {this.props.children}
        </li>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <li style={[this.styles.hidden, this.props.style]}>&nbsp;</li>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's hard to see why without seeing its parent(s), are you sure you pass props.active as `false`, have you logged from the render method?

Comment: yes i have tried logging in render and it don't change, and im passing in false in some of the cases but it's not reflected in the component

Comment: okay, to make debugging easier add some text to the `li`, maybe the css change isn't noticeable.

Comment: the thing is the children gets rendered (so it's easy to distinguish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem where that `Menu` parent where iterating over `this.props.children` and did not use the spread operation `{...this.props}`. so i where overriding the props to undefined and then defaultProps kicked in.

romseguy's answer made me think about checking all the parent components again

Answer (score 1):

Probably a problem with Radium as your code is working fine as demonstrated [here](http://codepen.io/romseguy/pen/avZmLa).

```js
React.render(<MenuItem active={false}>some text</MenuItem>, document.getElementById('app'));
```